# Windows 10 - Set up an OS-level proxy with authentication

Tags: windows-10, proxy

To connect with a certain server, I need to have always the same IP. For that purpose I created a private proxy and added authentication so that hackers wouldn't use it for malicious purposes.

Configuring the proxy on software like Firefox is a breeze. The problem is that web browsers aren't the only software that need to connect with this server. For this, I would like to configure my whole OS to be using the proxy.

I tried looking in Windows 10 network configuration, and I saw a place to put my proxy's IP address, but there is no option to include the username/password to connect.

[image: Windows Network Settings]

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes; Internet Options, setup a proxy.  Any application that uses proxy settings will then respect those settings.  An application does not have to respect those options though.

Comment: When you say "Internet Options", I figure you mean "Internet Options" -> "Connections" tab -> "LAN settings" button.

The problem is that there is no place there to specify username or password for the proxy.

Comment: The problem is that Windows doesn’t do the connection, it’s up to individual applications to read those settings and use them to connect to the proxy themselves. That means the software needs to support proxies. It’s the same with authentication of course. For your purposes, it may be more appropriate to set up a VPN. If you really can’t you need a helper program that adds the authentication information to proxy requests.

Comment: Would you know of any helper program that does that? And would setting a VPN guarantee I have always the same IP address?

Comment: No, unfortunately most of these programs (they act as a proxy themselves and forward request to an upstream proxy) are just made to deal with NTLM authentication because it isn't supported in most proxy-capable software. A VPN would work similar to a proxy but tunnel all network traffic, not just HTTP(S).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Windows 10 does not support user-name and password for the automatic proxy,
and this was done for security reasons.

You will need to setup a two-step proxy :

1. A local proxy server on your computer without user-name and password
2. The local proxy should connect to the real external proxy using the user-name and password

A possible solution is installing [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) together with
[proxy-password-automator](https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator), described as :

> proxy-password-automator
>  automatically send user/password to http
>   proxy server so you do not need to input it manually.

In theory, if you have a proxy server at `real_proxy_ip:8080`,
then run the following command to create a local proxy at `localhost:8081`

```
node proxy-login-automator.js -local_port 8081 -remote_host real_proxy_ip -remote_port 8080 -usr user -pwd pw
```

Then you can set Window's proxy ip:port to `localhost:8081`.

A more heavy-weight solution might be to use [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software)).
Other web proxies that might be of use are [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/),
[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com/), [Anon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/anonproxyserver/), [CCProxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/).

Comment: I like your answer but: @harrymc "Windows 10 does not support user-name and password for the automatic proxy, and this was done for security reasons." How do you know this? How do you explain that the other answer works if that where the case? Please remove this sentence or give a source.

Comment: @masterxilo: This answer dates from 3 years ago, and at that time Windows credentials didn't seem to work. The accepted answer says they now work when using Generic Credentials (which stands to reason since these are application-specific). Future readers should then pay attention to the other answer and test if it works for them.

Answer (score 17):

You can authenticate to the proxy using Windows credentials.

[image: Search windows credential in control panel]

Comment: Why downvote? this is a correct answer.

Comment: @desmati how exactly that answer helps?

Comment: The question specifically asks how to store a username / password at a system level. If the proxy credentials are specified in the Credential Manger, they will be used for all requests through that proxy.

Comment: I had to create the entry under Generic Credentials, not under Windows Credentials. Creating it  under Windows Credentials still prompted me for creds when I tried to use the proxy.

Comment: are there additional steps to this?  It didn't work for me.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work with Chrome or Chrome-Edge. Legacy IE recognized the credential setting though.

Comment: It's a wrong answer ffs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to : **@harrymc** answer above, another option :

---

### Setting Proxy Authentication via Squid Proxy

[Credits & Limitations of solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199424/squid-forward-to-another-proxy-with-authentication-details-for-the-parent-prox)

1. Install local proxy, e.g : [squid](https://squid.diladele.com/) for windows
2. After installing, open squid.conf file ( right mouse click on squid icon on task bar -> Open Squid Configuration
3. Put the following code
   please provide authenticated proxy ip only ( in our example : 10.1.2.3 - **not domain one** )

   ```
   http_access allow all
   http_port 3128

   coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
   refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
   refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
   refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
   refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
   refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

   cache_peer 10.1.2.3 parent 80 0 no-query default login=my_username:my_password

   never_direct allow all
   access_log none
   cache_log none
   ```
4. Restart Squid Service
5. **You now may call your local proxy, which will forward request to authenticated proxy and response back**

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://stackoverflow.com/' -Proxy 'http://127.0.0.1:3128'
   ```