# Windows Hotspot - Proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, hotspot

I need to create a wifi hotspot in my windows 10 so my IoT device can connect to it and use the proxy that I've set on my windows, The problem is my IoT does not support any kind of configuration to setup with proxy and I want to configure a network that has already bypass all requests through the proxy.

Is there any solution?

Comment: You cannot use a normal forward proxy if the devices do not support it. You need to set up a transparent proxy, and I'm not sure if there are options to do that on Windows.

Comment: What is the needed configuration?

Comment: I need my `Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter` pass every requests into something like this: `http://127.0.0.1:5042` @harrymc

Comment: Perhaps the tools from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/979727/windows-10-set-up-an-os-level-proxy-with-authentication) could help.

Comment: Nope!! @harrymc

Answer (score 0):

I need this feature too, but unfortunately it's not supported

Don't know if there is some 3rd app can do this, hotspot-with-proxy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).